# counteracting numerical instability in HMM training

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-models

I am training a HMM with Baum Welch for part of speech tagging. I am training the model with 79 hidden variables (part of speech tags) and 80,000 observed variables (words). I am working with log probabilities. To give you an idea, I defined the necessary arithmetic operations like so:

```
struct log_policy
{
    template<class T, class U>
    static auto mul(const T t1, const U t2)
    {
        return t1 + t2;
    }

    template<class T, class U>
    static auto div(const T t1, const U t2)
    {
        return t1 - t2;
    }

    template<class T, class U>
    static auto add(const T t1, const U t2)
    {
        return log(exp(t1) + exp(t2));
    }

    template<class T, class U>
    static auto sub(const T t1, const U t2)
    {
        return log(exp(t1) - exp(t2));
    }

    template<class T>
    static auto linear_scale(const T t)
    {
        return exp(t);
    }

    template<class T>
    static auto native_scale(const T t)
    {
        return log(t);
    }

    template<class T>
    constexpr static auto make_additive_neutral_element()
    {
        return -1 * std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
    }

    template<class T>
    constexpr static auto make_multiplicative_neutral_element()
    {
        return static_cast<T>(0);
    }

    template<class T>
    constexpr static auto make_annihilator()
    {
        return -1 * std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity();
    }
};
```

Anyway, besides working with log probabilities I still get numeric instability for longer training sentences. This is primarily due to the size of the set of observed variables. As the size is 80,000, each state in the HMM has an average emission probability of 1/80,000 for each word. I was wondering how to counteract this? Would reducing the number of emissions be a valid option?

To further illustrate: This is a section of a debug representation of the forward trellis after doing the forward algorithm on a training sequence. As you can see the right most fifth of the table is full of `-inf`, and they all appear at the same time... which I don't quite know why yet.

(The format for a cell is `<hidden variable human readable name> <hidden variable internal name and state ID> <probabiliy of cell> <backpointer>`)

```
($$(      (0)   :  -40.3203,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -78.1552,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -115.029,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -151.865,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -188.706,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -225.547,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -262.389,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -299.23,   -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -336.071,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -372.913,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -409.754,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -446.596,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -483.437,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -520.278,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -557.12,   -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -593.961,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -630.802,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -667.644,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -704.485,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -741.955,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$(      (0)   :  -inf,  -1)
($$,      (1)   :  -43.2152,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -77.935,   -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -114.923,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -151.76,   -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -188.602,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -225.444,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -262.285,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -299.127,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -335.968,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -372.809,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -409.651,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -446.492,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -483.333,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -520.175,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -557.016,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -593.857,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -630.699,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -667.54,   -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -704.382,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -741.667,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$,      (1)   :  -inf,  -1)
($$.      (2)   :  -40.3012,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -77.9027,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -114.861,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -151.692,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -188.534,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -225.375,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -262.217,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -299.058,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -335.899,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -372.741,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -409.582,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -446.423,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -483.265,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -520.106,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -556.948,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -593.789,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -630.63,   -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -667.472,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -704.313,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -741.444,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($$.      (2)   :  -inf,  -1)
($(       (3)   :  -45.7222,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -78.2411,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -115.133,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -151.978,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -188.82,   -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -225.661,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -262.502,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -299.344,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -336.185,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -373.026,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -409.868,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -446.709,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -483.551,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -520.392,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -557.233,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -594.075,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -630.916,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -667.757,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -704.599,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -742.137,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($(       (3)   :  -inf,  -1)
($,       (4)   :  -43.7637,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -78.1276,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -115.012,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -151.848,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -188.689,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -225.53,   -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -262.371,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -299.213,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -336.054,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -372.896,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -409.737,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -446.578,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -483.42,   -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -520.261,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -557.102,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -593.944,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -630.785,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -667.626,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -704.468,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -741.732,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($,       (4)   :  -inf,  -1)
($.       (5)   :  -43.5252,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -77.9508,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -114.713,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -151.56,   -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -188.401,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -225.243,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -262.084,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -298.926,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -335.767,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -372.608,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -409.45,   -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -446.291,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -483.132,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -519.974,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -556.815,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -593.656,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -630.498,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -667.339,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -704.18,   -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -741.349,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)  ($.       (5)   :  -inf,  -1)
```

When I reduce the number of emissions and thus increase the average emission probability the problem goes away. But I am unsure whether that is the right way to go about this as the more emissions the model is trained with the better it will perform later on.

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, concise pseudo code, and/or mathematics.  Not everyone here reads C++ code. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: What makes you think that you are observing numerical instability (as opposed to some other problem)?  What are the specific symptoms that make you think that?  What is your reasoning that makes you think those symptoms are caused by numerical instability, as opposed to something else?  Why do you find it worrisome/problematic that the rightmost fifth is full of `-inf`?  What did you expect to see there?  What do you mean by "rightmost fifth", and what does the "rightmost fifth" represent?  Don't force us to try to interpret your debug log format.

Comment: When I reduce the number of emissions and thus increase the average emission probability the problem goes away.  That is why I assume to be instability. I thought the table was self explanatory as it is the just the forward trellis. Each column has all the hidden variables in it and the table has as many columns as the training sequence is long. Each cell contains the forward probability of that hidden variable at the respective time step. The right most fifth is... are the columns on the right on the last fifth of the length of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Avoiding zero probabilities

You probably want to be using [additive smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing) when estimating probabilities from count data.

With a dictionary of 80,000 words, most of those words will be very rare: many of them might never appear anywhere in your training data, or will never appear associated with a particular part of speech.  Thus, your counts for those words will be zero.  That causes you to estimate an emission probability of zero, if you naively estimate the probability as a ratio of counts.  However, a zero probability is unlikely to be physically meaningful (I doubt that there is truly *zero* probability of outputting that word; instead, it's probably some small probability that's close to zero but not exactly zero).  Additive smoothing is one way to address this.

Lack of additive smoothing probably explains the `-inf`.  You are computing with [log-probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability).  A probability of zero corresponds to a log-probability of $-\infty$ (i.e., `-inf`).  Implement additive smoothing, and your `-inf`'s might largely go away.

### Numerical stability of log probabilities

While computing with [log probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_probability) does generally improve stability compared to computing with probabilities directly, there are some tricky aspects you must be careful of.

For instance, instead of adding probabilities by computing $\log(\exp(x)+\exp(y))$, it's usually better to compute $x + \log(1 + \exp(y-x))$ (assuming $y \ge x$; if $y <x$, swap $x,y$ before doing this computation).  This avoids loss of accuracy when $x,y$ are both small and are close to each other.  You might want to use a built-in library for computing the function $u \mapsto \log(1+u)$.  Some languages have built-in library functions for computing $\log(\exp(x)+\exp(y))$ in a numerically-stable way: it might be called something like `logsumexp`.

Other relevant references: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7480996/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2189716/14578, https://stackoverflow.com/q/42355196/781723, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23630277/781723.

Comment: Why would I do smoothing when I train the model unsupervised? If I smoothed the probabilities the average probability is still 1/80,000 as all states emit all words, thus why would it make a difference?

Comment: However the trick with the identity to $log(exp(x) + exp(y))$ apparently helped in this case.